# Why the Models not showing up in django website

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am making a news website and i have made a model of an image, title, description,url(for clickable image), but the final output is not just showing up and there is no error .

**Please also look into image links I have attached The output Screenshot and The admin Page screenshot**

[image: The output]

[image: AdminPage Screenshot]

**Main Code**

```html
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>World Vision</title>
    <!-- plugin css for this page -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="{% static 'techworld/assets/vendors/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css' %}"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'techworld/assets/vendors/aos/dist/aos.css/aos.css' %}" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="{% static 'techworld/assets/vendors/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css' %}"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="{% static 'techworld/assets/vendors/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css' %}"
    />
    <!-- End plugin css for this page -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'techworld/assets/images/favicon.png' %}" />
    <!-- inject:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'techworld/assets/css/style.css' %}">
    <!-- endinject -->


    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="{% static 'techworld/box/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'techworld/box/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- main css -->
    <link href="{% static 'techworld/box/css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- modernizr -->
    <script src="{% static 'techworld/box/js/modernizr.js' %}"></script>


    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="{% static 'techworld/worldtime/assets/vendors/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css' %}"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'techworld/worldtime/assets/vendors/aos/dist/aos.css/aos.css' %}" />

    <!-- End plugin css for this page -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'techworld/worldtime/assets/images/favicon.png' %}" />

    <!-- inject:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'techworld/worldtime/assets/css/style.css' %}">
    <!-- endinject -->


    <title>Tech-World</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Preloader -->
    <div id="preloader">
        <div class="pre-container">
            <div class="spinner">
                <div class="double-bounce1"></div>
                <div class="double-bounce2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end Preloader -->
<!--  Intro Slide  
  <div class="container-fluid">
    
    <section class="box-intro">
      <div class="table-sell">
        <h1 class="box-headline letters rotate-2">
          <span class="box-words-wrapper">
            <b class="is-visible">Choose What you Read</b>
            <b>&nbsp;To see all the latest talks Scroll down</b>
          </span>
        </h1>
        <h5>More than everything You need</h5>
      </div>

      <div class="mouse">
        <div class="scroll"></div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>-->
  <!--  End Intro slide  -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- box header -->
        
        <!-- end box header -->

        

        <!-- box-intro -->
        <section class="box-intro">
            <div class="table-cell">
                <h1 class="box-headline letters rotate-2">
                    <span class="box-words-wrapper">
                        <b class="is-visible">design. mbkm</b>
                        <b>&nbsp;coding.</b>
                        <b>graphic.</b>
                    </span>
            </h1>
                <h5>We always server more than everythin you need </h5>
            </div>

            <div class="mouse">
                <div class="scroll"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- end box-intro -->
    </div>

    <!-- portfolio div -->
    <div class="portfolio-div">
        <div class="portfolio">
            <div class="no-padding portfolio_container">
                <!-- single work -->
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6  fashion logo">
                    <a href="single-project.html" class="portfolio_item">
                        <img src="{% static 'techworld/img/apple.png' %}" alt="image" class="img-responsive" />
                        <div class="portfolio_item_hover">
                            <div class="portfolio-border clearfix">
                                <div class="item_info">
                                    <span>Latest Talks from Apple</span>
                                    <em>Apple TechWorld</em>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- end single work -->


                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 ads graphics">
                        <a href="#" class="portfolio_item">
                            <img src="{% static 'techworld/img/tablet.png' %}" alt="image" class="img-responsive" />
                            <div class="portfolio_item_hover">
                                <div class="portfolio-border clearfix">
                                    <div class="item_info">
                                        <span>Latest Productivity Tablets</span>
                                        <em>Latest Tablets</em>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 photography">
                    <a href="#" class="portfolio_item">
                        <img src="{% static 'techworld/img/mobile.jpg' %}" alt="image" class="img-responsive" />
                        <div class="portfolio_item_hover">
                            <div class="portfolio-border clearfix">
                                <div class="item_info">
                                    <span>Its all About SmartPhones</span>
                                    <em>Reviews,Latest news and much more</em>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>


                <!--  Single workflow area end   -->
                <!--  Dual workflow area part 2  -->

                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 fashion ads">
                    <a href="#" class="portfolio_item">
                        <img src="{% static 'techworld/img/samsung.png' %}" alt="image" class="img-responsive" />
                        <div class="portfolio_item_hover">
                            <div class="portfolio-border clearfix">
                                <div class="item_info">
                                    <span>Empty space</span>
                                    <em>Empty space</em>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 graphics ads">
                    <a href="#" class="portfolio_item">
                        <img src="{% static 'techworld/img/samsung.png' %}" alt="image" class="img-responsive" />
                        <div class="portfolio_item_hover">
                            <div class="portfolio-border clearfix">
                                <div class="item_info">
                                    <span>Empty space</span>
                                    <em>Empty space</em>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 photography">
                    <a href="#" class="portfolio_item">
                        <img src="{% static 'techworld/img/samsung.png' %}" alt="image" class="img-responsive" />
                        <div class="portfolio_item_hover">
                            <div class="portfolio-border clearfix">
                                <div class="item_info">
                                    <span>Empty space</span>
                                    <em>Empty space</em>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 graphics ads">
                    <a href="#" class="portfolio_item">
                        <img src="{% static 'techworld/img/samsung.png' %}" alt="image" class="img-responsive" />
                        <div class="portfolio_item_hover">
                            <div class="portfolio-border clearfix">
                                <div class="item_info">
                                    <span>Empty space</span>
                                    <em>Empty space</em>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 graphics ads">
                    <a href="#" class="portfolio_item">
                        <img src="{% static 'techworld/img/samsung.png' %}" alt="image" class="img-responsive" />
                        <div class="portfolio_item_hover">
                            <div class="portfolio-border clearfix">
                                <div class="item_info">
                                    <span>Empty space</span>
                                    <em>Empty space</em>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 graphics ads">
                    <a href="#" class="portfolio_item">
                        <img src="{% static 'techworld/img/samsung.png' %}" alt="image" class="img-responsive" />
                        <div class="portfolio_item_hover">
                            <div class="portfolio-border clearfix">
                                <div class="item_info">
                                    <span>Empty space</span>
                                    <em>Empty space</em>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 graphics ads">
                    <a href="#" class="portfolio_item">
                        <img src="{% static 'techworld/img/samsung.png' %}" alt="image" class="img-responsive" />
                        <div class="portfolio_item_hover">
                            <div class="portfolio-border clearfix">
                                <div class="item_info">
                                    <span>Empty space</span>
                                    <em>Empty space</em>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>






                
            </div>
            <!-- end portfolio_container -->
        </div>
        <!-- portfolio -->
    </div>
    <!-- end portfolio div -->

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>



<div class="container-scroller">
      <div class="main-panel">
        <!-- partial:partials/_navbar.html -->
        

        <!-- partial -->
        
        <div class="content-wrapper">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row" data-aos="fade-up">
              {% for AllProject in allprojects %}
              <div class="col-xl-8 stretch-card grid-margin">
                <div class="position-relative">
                  {% if AllProject.url %}
                  <a href="{{ AllProject.url }}"><img
                    src="{{ AllProject.image.url }}"
                    alt="banner"
                    class="img-fluid" />
                  </a>
                  {% else %}
                  <img src="{{ AllProject.image.url }}" alt="banner" class="img-fluid" />
                  {% endif %}
                  
                  <div class="banner-content">
                    <div class="badge badge-danger fs-12 font-weight-bold mb-3">
                      global news
                    </div>
                    <h1 class="mb-0">{{ AllProject.title }}</h1>
                    <h1 class="mb-2">
                      {{ AllProject.description }}
                    </h1>
                    <div class="fs-12">
                      <span class="mr-2">Photo </span>10 Minutes ago
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              {% endfor %}
              
              
            </div>
            <div class="row" data-aos="fade-up">
              <div class="col-lg-3 stretch-card grid-margin">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h2>Category</h2>
                    <ul class="vertical-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Politics</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">International</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Finance</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Health care</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Administration</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Game</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Art</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Kids</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-9 stretch-card grid-margin">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    {% for Flash in flashes %}
                    <div class="row">
                      
                      <div class="col-sm-4 grid-margin">
                        <div class="position-relative">
                          <div class="rotate-img">
                            {% if Flash.url %}
                            <a href="{{ Flash.url }}">
                              <img src="{{ project.image.url }}" alt="thumb" class="img-fluid" />
                            </a>
                            {% else %}
                            <img src="{{ project.image.url }}" alt="thumb" class="img-fluid" />
                            {% endif %}
                          </div>
                          <div class="badge-positioned">
                            <span class="badge badge-danger font-weight-bold"
                              >Flash news</span
                            >
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-8  grid-margin">
                        <h2 class="mb-2 font-weight-600">
                          {{ Flash.title }}
                        </h2>
                        <div class="fs-13 mb-2">
                          <span class="mr-2">Photo </span>10 Minutes ago
                        </div>
                        <p class="mb-0">
                          {{ Flash.description }}
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
              {% endblock %}

                    
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import AllProject
from .models import Flash


def techhome(request):
    allprojects = AllProject.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'techworld/techhome.html', {'allprojects':allprojects})

def Flashnews(request):
    flashes = Flash.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'techworld/techhome1.html', {'flashes':flashes})
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class AllProject(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='techworld/images/')
    url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Flash(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='techworld/images/')
    url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Please also look into image links I have attached The output Screenshot and The admin Page screenshot

Comment: And also all the migrations are done

Comment: You have an `endblock` but there is no start of the block anywhere.

Comment: There is start of block at the top of the document but i Hav'nt included it as the document is very long

Comment: Blocks are the most important parts of a Django template. With an incomplete block structure we can trace the error. Please create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)!

Comment: ok i am attaching the whole code till endblock

Comment: <img src="{{ project.image.url }}" alt="thumb" class="img-fluid" />
What is the `project`? You are not passing it from view.

Comment: Please remember that MRE starts with an M as in "minimal"!

Answer (score 0):

You are using both `allprojects` and `flashes` in your template, but you pass them in separate views to different templates.

It's not clear (to me, at least) which of these views corresponds to this template. I'm guessing you're trying to use the `techhome()` view, since you appear to be unable to get the Flash data to appear. You'll need to pass both `allprojects` and `flashes` as `context` to the template so they can be rendered. If, for example, you wish `techhome()` to display both, you could do the following:

```py
def techhome(request):
    allprojects = AllProject.objects.all()
    flashes = Flash.objects.all()
    context = {'allprojects':allprojects, 'flashes':flashes}
    return render(request, 'techworld/techhome.html', context)
```